# CMD FFMpeg Converting from one directory to another

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I have the folder which has the ffmpeg.exe. In this folder I have 2 folders: MP4 and MP3. In the folder called MP4, I have a bunch of video I want just the audio from. I want to convert all of them to mp3 and stick them in the MP3 folder. I have the code to convert but don't know how to deal with the directories. I can move all of the mp4's to the root with the exe and then all of them will convert to mp3 right there, but I want to organize them in their directories. How can I edit my code to work with the directories in the root folder?

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%G" -acodec mp3 "%~nG.mp3"
```

Edit: tried lit's code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b "mp4\*.mp4"') DO ffmpeg -i "%~G" -acodec mp3 "mp3\%~nG.mp3"
```

and tried a couple different edits and kept getting the result "No such file or directory"

[View cmd output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGMCo.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are very close. It looks like that all you need to do is specify the directories for the source and target files.

```
CD /D d:\path\to\ffmpeg\dir
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b /A:-D "mp4\*.mp4"') DO ffmpeg -i "%~fG" -acodec mp3 "mp3\%~nG.mp3"
```

Remember that if you put this into a .bat or .cmd script that the `%` character needs to be doubled.

Comment: It came closer. It managed to see the files in the source directory, but I get an error saying "no such file or directory".

Comment: Please edit the question to copy/paste the text of the command and error message(s). If this is in a .bat script, be sure to remove or comment out `@ECHO OFF`.

Comment: I edited the question. Right now I'm just running everything straight from cmd not a bat file or any kind of file. Included a screenshot as well with the code, work, and error.

Comment: Using only `"%~G"` will not provide the directory path. I edited the answer to use `"%~fG"` which will.